# If M is compact and N is connected, then locally isometry is symmetric?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I am studying for the qualifying exams of my PhD, and I found the following exercise in the reference book: If $M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold, $N$ is a connected Riemannian manifold and $M$ is locally isometric to $N$, then $N$ is locally isometric to $M$.

I can't figure out how to use the book definition of local isometry to get the result. Namely, the book defines local isometry as follows: $M$ is locally isometric to $N$ if for all $p\in M$ there exists an isometry between an open neighborhood of $p$ to an open set of $N$.

Thanks.

Comment: Let $M = S^2$, and $N$ be a plane with a spherical bump.

Comment: Is this a counterexample? So, the statement of the exercise is wrong?

Comment: When you make things precise it is a counterexample. Unless there is some additional constraint that you overlooked, the statement of the exercise thus is wrong.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try make things precise here.